# cannot receive Jersey server sent events from Angular 10 app

Tags: angular, tomcat, iis, jersey, arr

I want to use Server Side Events (SSE) to track batch process running on the server.

The client is an Angular 10 app sending requests to an IIS 10 web server, which uses ARR to forward the requests to Tomcat 9, and I use Jersey 2.32 to manage SSE requests.

As I need authentification, I also use sse.js to be able to add authorization headers.

Sending the requests works fine. They are received by Jersey and I can see in Tomcat console that messages are properly sent (see Java code below).

Unfortunately, I never receive any message in the Angular client app, the only thing I have checked using the browser console is that the event source is set.

The SSE get request is pending and never receives an answer.

I have googled a lot to see what is wrong in my code or what I need to configure in IIS, ARR or Tomcat, but I am stucked, so any help appreciated.

Here is the code used in the Angular app.

Monitoring service:

```
export class BatchProcessMonitoringService {

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private sseService: ServerSideEventsService) { }

  public getMonitoringData(url: string, authorizationString: string, formData: FormData): Observable<string> {
    return this.getServerSentEvent(url, authorizationString, formData);
  }

  // get event source (SSE)
  private getServerSentEvent(url: string, authorizationString: string, data: FormData): Observable<string> {

    return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      const eventSource = this.sseService.getEventSourceWithGet(url, authorizationString, data);
      console.log('batch process event source set');
      console.log(eventSource);
      eventSource.stream();
      eventSource.onmessage = (event: any) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          console.log('batch process event received in angular');
          console.log(event);
          observer.next(event);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error: any) => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          console.log('batch process event error in angular');
          console.log(error);
          observer.error(error);
        });
      };
    });
  }

  public closeConnection(): void {
    this.sseService.closeEventSource();
  }

}
```

SSE service:

```
export class ServerSideEventsService {
  eventSource: SSE;

  constructor(
    private sseService: ServerSideEventsService
  ) { }

  // create an event source of POST request
  public getEventSourceWithPost(url: string, authorizationString: string, formData: FormData): SSE {
    return this.buildEventSource(url, authorizationString, 'POST', formData);
  }

  // create an event source of GET request
  public getEventSourceWithGet(url: string, authorizationString: string, formData: FormData): SSE {
    return this.buildEventSource(url, authorizationString, 'GET', formData);
  }

  // build the event source
  private buildEventSource(url: string, authorizationString: string, meth: string, formData: FormData): SSE {
    const options = this.buildOptions(meth, authorizationString, formData);
    this.eventSource = new SSE(url, options);
    console.log('sse service this.eventSource');
    console.log(this.eventSource);
    // add listener
    this.eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e: any) => {
      console.log('sse service message received');
      console.log(e);
      return e.data;
    });
    return this.eventSource;
  }

  // build query options
  private buildOptions(
    meth: string,
    authorizationString: string,
    formData: FormData
  ): {
    payload: FormData;
    method: string;
    headers: { Authorization: string };
  } {
    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: authorizationString
    };
    return {
      payload: formData,
      method: meth,
      headers: headerDict
    };
  }

  public closeEventSource(): void {
    if (!!this.eventSource) {
      this.eventSource.close();
    }
  }
```

And here is the code of the Java GET method called:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{userId_timestamp}")
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void getUserImportProcessEvent(
            @Context SseEventSink eventSink,
            @Context Sse sse,
            @PathParam("userId_timestamp") String userId_timestamp) {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // ... code that waits 1 second
                    final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                    eventBuilder.name("message");
                    eventBuilder.data(String.class, "Hello world " + i + "!");
                    final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);
                    System.out.println("write event: " + i);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing the event.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    eventOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. My Jersey Java code was not correct, here is the right code.

```
    // Server Side Events with User Import process monitoring data
    @GET
    @Path("/{userId_timestamp}")
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput getUserImportProcessEvent(
            @PathParam("userId_timestamp") String userId_timestamp) {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    // ... code that waits 1 second
                    final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                    eventBuilder.name("message");
                    eventBuilder.data(String.class, "Hello world " + i + "!");
                    final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                    eventOutput.write(event);
                    System.out.println("write event: " + i);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error when writing the event.", e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    eventOutput.close();
                } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return eventOutput;
    }
```